# Can't seem to derive the formula for the electric field over a square sheet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I'm trying to derive the formula for the electric field a height $h$ above the center of a uniformly charged square sheet with sides $2a$.

To do so I'm using the formula for the electric field above the center of a line segment with length $2L$ and uniform charge density:

$$E = \frac{2k_e\lambda L}{h\sqrt{h^2+L^2}}$$

Then using the fact that $\lambda(2L) = Q$, I get

$$E = \frac{k_eQ}{h\sqrt{h^2+L^2}}$$

Then I can cut the square sheet into line segments with differential charge $dq = \sigma dA$ and differential area $dA = 2adx$.  I just have to take into account that I only need the vertical component of the electric fields and integrate:

$$\begin{align}E &= k_e(\sigma 2a)\int_{-a}^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}\sqrt{h^2+x^2+a^2}}\cos(\theta) \\ &= 4a\sigma k_e\int_0^a \frac{dx}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}\sqrt{h^2+x^2+a^2}}\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2}} \\ &= 4a\sigma hk_e\int_0^a \frac{dx}{(h^2+x^2)\sqrt{h^2+x^2+a^2}}\end{align}$$

I can't figure out any way to integrate this, but Mathematica is giving me

$$E = 4\sigma k_e\arctan\left(\frac{a^2}{h\sqrt{h^2+a^2+a^2}}\right)$$

However I know the answer is supposed to be

$$E = 2\sigma k_e\left[4\arctan\left(\sqrt{1+a^2/(2h^2)}\right)-\pi\right]$$

I can see these are not just the same answer in different forms by plugging in 1s for all the constants and evaluating.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the integral be from $\frac{-a}{2}$ to $\frac{a}{2}$?

Comment: Whoops.  It should be from $-a$ to $a$ (I've changed it now).  But that doesn't fix the problem because that just gives an extra factor of $2$ to my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the formula for electric field above the center of a line segment with length $2L$ is correct? I don't think so.

Comment: Though I did it a different way than him, my answer to that part agrees with [this person's answer](https://physicstasks.eu/659/charged-line-segment) so I don't think that part's wrong.

Comment: According to my notes: the Electric Field strength for a rod of length $L$ should be $E=\frac{2K\lambda L}{h(4h^2+L^2)^{1/2}}$.

Comment: Which is exactly what I derived.  I just used a rod of length $2L$ instead of $L$.

Comment: Ohh, I missed that.

Comment: @JayJay What do you mean the "plane perpendicular to the square sheet".  This is in $3D$ -- there are no planes perpendicular to a square sheet.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're doing now. Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is flawless: there is nothing the matter with it. Both formulae are equivalent, and can be shown to be so with this identity:

$tan^{-1}(\frac{2u}{u^2-1})=2tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{u}+/-n\pi)$

Substitute $u^2=1+\frac{2a^2}{z^2}$ and you'll find they are equal.